# How do I add Unix executables to the Parental Controls 'Allowed Apps' whitelist?

Tags: unix, parental-controls, binary

One example is some of [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)'s executables, I get popups saying "You don't have permission to use the application "karabiner_grabber." as well as `karabiner_console_user_server` and a few others. They all appear to be located in `/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/bin`.

If I select 'Always Allow' on the popup, it just comes up again within about 15 seconds.

The executables don't appear under the list in Preferences > Parental Controls > Apps > Limit Applications on this Mac > Allowed Apps

I can drag them in from Finder, but they disappear if I exit the preferences then go back in.

Comment: I'd think you would write an applescript to call karabiner.

Answer (score -1):

You could take the approach [suggested here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82982/9225).

Open the terminal, then switch to your child's user account with:

`su - [username here]`.

Go to the bin directory you mentioned above:

`cd /Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/bin`

Then, give all users permission to execute all the files in the bin directory:

`chmod a+x *`

Comment: `chmod u+x` gives execute permissions to the *owner* of the files, not to the current user.

Comment: So it would have to be `chmod a+x *`, I guess. Some folks may or may not want to do that. In my case, that command resolved the problem and I no longer get the annoying Karabiner dialogs on my child's account.

Comment: Parental Control doesn't rely on Unix permissions at all (would be difficult anyway, with several managed users having different sets of allowed applications).